# How to share javascript in nativescript?

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

I am building an app using nativescript and i've noticed i have a ton of repeated code.  The slideout drawer for example would have to be replicated on every page.  How do I share the backend javascript so I can just load in a file or whatever instead of having to rewrite the code on every page?

For example I have a slideout drawer with view permissions and its called like this:

```
if (access[0]['page'] == 'Checks' && access[0]['enabled'] == true) {pageData.set("Checks", true);}
if (access[1]['page'] == 'Timeclock' && access[1]['enabled'] == true) {pageData.set("Timeclock", true);}
if (access[2]['page'] == 'Invoices' && access[2]['enabled'] == true) {pageData.set("Invoices", true);}
if (access[3]['page'] == 'EEInfo' && access[3]['enabled'] == true) {pageData.set("EEInfo", true);}
if (access[4]['page'] == 'CLInfo' && access[4]['enabled'] == true) {pageData.set("CLInfo", true);}

drawer = page.getViewById("drawer");
```

I don't want to have to repeat this on every page.

Comment: Create a function on a page then include and call it from every page. You will have to put that call on every page you wanted.

Comment: @HardikVaghani would that be with an import? how do i include another file?

Comment: with `var test = include('../sometest')`